# How to export Sling Model into JSON and render it to end user?

Tags: aem, sling, sling-models

Let's assume I have the following model:

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public class BasicScheduleModel {
   @Self
   protected Resource resource;
   protected Envelope envelope;
   protected Status status;
   protected Metadata metadata;
   protected Data data;
   protected Messages messages;
   ........
```

How can I render this model to end user as a JSON?

I know that it is possible to convert java class to JSON using `GSON` library, but in this case I should introduce new field and initialize it in @PostConstruct method:

```
private String json;

@PostContruct
private void init() {
    this.json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(this);
}

private String getJson() {
    return this.json;
}
```

And than use this model in html using sightly(it is necessary to  new create component)

```
<sly data-sly-use.model="com.somewebsite.models.BasicScheduleModel">
${model.json @ context='unsafe'}
</sly>
```

Is there an elegant solution without of component creating?

Comment: you need this JSON within sighlty or as an endpoint ?

Comment: @SharathMadappa as end point, when user requests /some/path/shcedule.json he will get JSON representation of model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on 6.3 + you can use the sling model exporter feature to do this,

https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#exporter-framework-since-130-1

Change your code to

```
@Model(adaptable = Resource.class, resourceType = "<resourcetype-here>") 
@Exporter(name = "jackson", extensions = "json")
```

Requests to `<path-to-resource>.model.json` will return the model in JSON format. You can override the selector to be something else apart from 'model' via configurations in `Exporter` annotation.

Comment: Also I added selector configuration @Exporter(name = "jackson", extensions = "json", selector = ""), to have request without selector. Thank you a lot

Comment: @cylinder.y not having a selector can lead to un-expected behaviour. AEM uses the json output for rendering dialogs etc.. by sending processed response instead of dump of resource/properties will break such functionality

Comment: but this model only used for representing JSON response, this resource-type doesn't have any configuration